# Java synchronisation with infinispan

Tags: java, spring, synchronization, infinispan, thread-synchronization

I need to display number of users currently logged in to an application..
I am using one cache to store the current number of user.
And i am doing this operations,
When the user logged to an application i am fetching the number of users from the cache and incrementing the value by 1 since one more user has logged in.
But i am facing problem when multiple users logged at the same time..
Can any plz help me resolve this issue?

I need to display number of users currently logged in to an application..

I am using one cache to store the current number of user.

And i am doing this operations,

When the user logged to an application i am fetching the number of users from the cache and incrementing the value by 1 since one more user has logged in.

But i am facing problem when multiple users logged at the same time..

Can any plz help me resolve this issue?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to implement this:

- using counters https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/hotrod_java/hotrod_java.html#remotecache_countermanager-hotrod-client-api
- using transactions https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/hotrod_java/hotrod_java.html#hotrod_transactions
- using versioned operations